# Regression - predict n numbers based on another n numbers

Tags: regression

I'd like to get a recommendation how to attack a problem of predicting multiple numbers.
Training data contains 4 columns, each says a probability of record being in the bucket. So, for example:
`X = [0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 0.0]`
and
corresponding output should be e.g. `Y = [0.8, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1]`.
Each row should sum to 1.0

What type of approach would you recommend?

I already tried simple neural network with 4 neurons in the last layer and softmax activation but wondering if there is a better solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What's Y?
softmax tends to give a low variance probabilty

Comment: let's say I have a system that estimates a age distribution in a group of people. X says their age distribution. For example x[0] is `0-18 years, x[1] = 19-40 years, x[2] = 41-60 years and x[3] is 61+ years. x[0] = 0.25` means 25% of people belong to the age group 0-18 years. And Y contains real distribution.

Comment: Still confused. When creating the dataset, how did you create X and Y?
Also, how will you use the predictor afterwards?

Comment: You can have an image of people and would like to estimate their ages. There is a system that generates these estimates (X) but I know it's not entirely correct (because I have several thousands of manually labelled images) and I'd like to build a system that reduce the error. HTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using an **encoder-decoder structure based on LSTM-RNN for sequence-to-sequence learning**; it will provide you with exactly what you want. A link that I find very helpful is:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/define-encoder-decoder-sequence-sequence-model-neural-machine-translation-keras/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, it is very interesting. Unfortunately, I think using seq 2 seq approach I think I can't guarantee that generated numbers will sum to 100%.

Comment: True. What you can do is to insert a custom "Lambda Layer" AFTER the seq2seq structure to sum all the outputs into 1 and train the network to learn it! Take a look at how Lambda Layers works in Keras documentation and also check this very helpful example [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886195/how-to-use-lambda-layer-in-keras] :)